# Split pandas DataFrame into approximately the same chunks

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to split this DataFrame into a predefined number of chunks of **approximately the same size**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
    "value": [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]})


#     user  value
# 0      A    0.3
# 1      A    0.4
# 2      B    0.5
# 3      C    0.6
# 4      C    0.7
# 5      C    0.8
```

The DataFrame is large (millions of lines) so the code should be more or less efficient.
The problem is that certain user should only be present in one of the chunks.

E.g. if the number of chunks is 3 then:

- first chunk should have lines [0, 1]
- second chunk should have line 2, no line 3 since line 3 is for user C
- third chunk should have lines [3, 4, 5]

```
# Chunk #1 (DataFrame):
# 0      A    0.3
# 1      A    0.4

# Chunk #2 (DataFrame):
# 2      B    0.5

# Chunk #3 (DataFrame):
# 3      C    0.6
# 4      C    0.7
# 5      C    0.8
```

This chunking in 3 pieces will be incorrect since user C will be present in 2 chunks:

```
# Chunk #1 (DataFrame):
# 0      A    0.3
# 1      A    0.4

# Chunk #2 (DataFrame):
# 2      B    0.5
# 3      C    0.6

# Chunk #3 (DataFrame):
# 4      C    0.7
# 5      C    0.8
```

I think that some solution when we do *groupby* by user first and then split this *DataFrameGroupBy* object in chunks should suffice.

Comment: Can you please add your ideal output how it should like? Should it be a list of dataframes split by users?

Comment: what happens when n=2?

Comment: @sophocles, thank you for your comment! It should be a list of DataFrames of approximately the same size but one user should be only in a single resulting DataFrame.

Comment: @anky, pretty flexible about this one, both cases [[0,1,2], [3, 4, 5]] and [[0,1], [2, 3, 4, 5]] will suffice. But of course some users will have 2 value and some hundreds.

Comment: Do you need to keep the ordering? e.g. you could split in groups with `groupby("user")` and then merge together groups to reach the desired final number of chunks. This way you may end grouping together users that are not close in the original dataframe, is this ok?

Comment: @filippo, this should be all right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn our `user` column into a categorical one and use `qcut` for uniform height binning. Unfortunately `qcut` fails to find unique bin edges for discontinuous distributions so you might have some issue if one user is over represented. You could use `duplicates="drop"` but you won't always have the number bins you requested as some will be clumped together.

Guess you will have to write some algorithm for proper rebinning, couldn't find anything ready out of the box.

Here's an example with `pd.qcut`.

Let's build a dummy dataset

```
user = np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"], 10000)
value = np.random.random(size=user.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame({"user": user, "value": value})
print(df.user.value_counts())

E    1329
C    1281
G    1277
F    1260
H    1231
D    1223
A    1205
B    1194
Name: user, dtype: int64
```

assign an integer code to each unique user and rebin with `qcut`

```
codes = df.user.astype("category").cat.codes    
nbins = 3
df["bin"] = pd.qcut(codes, nbins, labels=False)
df.groupby("user").bin.value_counts()
```

let's check the results

```
print(df.bin.value_counts())
1    3788
0    3629
2    2583
Name: bin, dtype: int64

print(df.groupby("user").bin.value_counts())
user  bin
A     0      1266
B     0      1158
C     0      1205
D     1      1255
E     1      1246
F     1      1287
G     2      1274
H     2      1309
Name: bin, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is a brilliant recipe - pure gold - thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Will this suffice?

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('user')
df_list = [df for user, df in df_grouped]
```

---

```
Out[1352]: 
[  user  value
 0    A    0.3
 1    A    0.4,
   user  value
 2    B    0.5,
   user  value
 3    C    0.6
 4    C    0.7
 5    C    0.8]
```

This runs relatively fast on my machine:

```
>>> df.shape
(7200000, 2)

>>> print(end - start)
0.532534122467041
```

Comment: or maybe this: `df_list = {user:df for user, df in df_grouped}`

Comment: @sophocles thank you for your reply, but I don't see a number of chunks in this solution. I need a list of DataFrames of approximately the same size. Each DataFrame may have multiple users, but no single user's values should be in several DataFrames.

Comment: this only answers part of the question, you need to split the dataframe by user and regroup them into roughly uniform sized chunks, at least as far as I understood

Comment: Apologies, i am not able to address the changes now. I will have to postpone the changes until later or tomorrow. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `np.split` with some conditions in place checking if the chunks are same as the no of elements in user, then split across user, else split keeping the first n users in the list:

```
def split_fun(data,n):
    cond = len(set(data['user'])) == n
    f = data['user'].factorize()[0]+1
    if cond:
        p = np.where(np.diff(f)>0)[0]+1
    else:
        p= np.where(np.diff((f>n).view('i1'))>0)[0]+1
    return np.split(data,p)
```

---

Sample Runs:

```
split_fun(df,2)
[  user  value
 0    A    0.3
 1    A    0.4
 2    B    0.5,
   user  value
 3    C    0.6
 4    C    0.7
 5    C    0.8]

split_fun(df,3)

[  user  value
 0    A    0.3
 1    A    0.4,
   user  value
 2    B    0.5,
   user  value
 3    C    0.6
 4    C    0.7
 5    C    0.8]
```